# Should actions only be used when updating state?

Tags: redux

Reducers listen for actions of a certain type and then update the store as needed, but should you use an action without changing the store?

Maybe on route changes or on button clicks so that what the user does shows up in timemachine, or is this abusing actions?

Answer (score 0):

Actions are linked to reducers through their 'type', in general actions should be linked with at least one reducer.

It seems like you can achieve the functionality you are looking for by creating a function inside your component that is your method called by the onClick, submit, or whatever activity happens, something like this:

```
myOnCLickMethod(passedInfo){
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    //any JavaScript code you need
    dispatch(myAction(passedInfo))
}
```

This ensures you can do anything you want that doesn't touch the state while still allowing for actions to fire and state changes when that activity happens.

Answer (score 0):

An action is a call for state change. So if route changes or button clicks don't change the state of your app, you shouldn't use actions for them. Maybe log is more relevant in this scenario.